# Open Database mysql.gz

Tags: mysql

I want to open a 300 MB database downloaded to my computer. The database is called `database-name.mysql.gz`.

When I open the file called `database-name.mysql.gz` I get a file called `database-name.mysql.gz.cpgz`.

I have tried decompressing the GZ file using command line:

```
tar -xzf <your file>
```

not unzip unlike in the article since you're not using a .zip file which gave me an error: tar:

> Unrecognized archive format.

I have also tried

```
gunzip < database-name.mysql.gz | mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

but I don't really understand what USERNAME should be and the command returns

> gunzip: unknown compression format

How can I open the database and see its content?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to another person's [question](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/939036?answerId=4468914022#4468914022) about gz.cpgz file-types suggests that it may have been compressed twice. Other searches show people having [problems](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate_files/issues/1595030) [opening](https://github.com/amonapp/amon/issues/27) them but this is down to software not expecting files to be zipped up twice in their cases.

You don't say what operating system you are on but, from what you've posted, I'll take a guess that you have access to the `file` command to help identify what type file you have.

`file database-name.mysql.gz` will show that you have a file that can be unzipped using `gunzip` as you've already done.

Now run `file database-name.mysql.gz.cpgz` to see what this file's type is. If it comes back as gzip file again then you can `gunzip` it again.

A MySQL backup is just a text file, so if it reports it as so then you're safe to check it out further. Since it's over 300MB I wouldn't recommend opening it in your text editor. Instead use the `head` command to check out the top few lines:
`head <yourfile.sql>`

If you're Windows user [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) will be able to tell you if the gz.cpgz is an archive or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot KevH! Now I understand that the file is ASCII Text with very long lines. And it is a MySQL Dump. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Casper. Happy to help!
Can you mark the question as answered? It will help others in the future should they have the same query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The database is called database-name.mysql.gz.

That's *not* a database.
It's just a file.

> When I open the file ... I get a file called database-name.mysql.gz.cpgz

That's not a database *either*. 
It's some *other* sort of file.

> I want to open a 300 MB database downloaded to my computer.

Who *supplied* you with this file?

Have you tried asking *them* what format it might be in, and how you might go about getting it "into" MySQL?

You *do* have MySQL installed and running on your computer, don't you?

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this. I have asked the supplier. Yes I have MySQL installed and running. Thank you for the clarification!